# Minimum-size equal-width wrapping columns in CSS

Tags: css, css-grid

I have an arbitrary number of elements in my HTML with arbitrary content. I want them to be aligned in columns and all have the same size. If a row overflows, I want them to wrap, but still keep the same size. The size of every column should be as small as possible, i.e. the largest column determines the size for all of them.

For the purposes of this post, my HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>Col 1</div>
  <div>Col 2</div>
  <div>Col 3</div>
</div>
```

The first thing I tried was CSS Grid with `auto-fit`:

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

This works, but the columns have a maximum width of 100px that they cannot grow beyond:
https://codepen.io/diesieben07/pen/qBxMXXj

As has been discussed in many other questions, using auto-fit with min-content is not allowed per the spec.
How can I achieve the desired layout? Flex or other layout options are also welcome if they work better for this case.

Comment: Basically, you can't. CSS-Grid can't detect the widest column and apply this to all the other columns. I'm not aware of any layout method that could.

Comment: That is most unfortunate. It seems a common task one would like to do with CSS...

Answer (score -2):

To solve your column issue, apply the following css code. I hope your problem will be solved.

```css
.row {
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.row > * {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col with a lot longer text</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
  <div>Col</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution:

- uses a hardcoded number of columns

- uses a hardcoded number of rows

- does not produce equal-width columns